# Why did the angel who destroyed Sodom have to visit Avraham?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, malach-angel, abraham, vayera

רש"י בראשית  \ וירא יח,ב

והנה שלשה אנשים **אֶחָד לְבַשֵׂר אֶת שָׂרָה וְאֶחָד לַהֲפֹךְ אֶת סְדוֹם וְאֶחָד לְרַפְּאוֹת אֶת אַבְרָהָם,** ... וּרְפָאֵל שֶׁרִפָּא אֶת אַבְרָהָם הָלַךְ מִשָּׁם לְהַצִּיל אֶת לוֹט. (בראשית רבה):

Rashi Beraishis / Vayera 18:2

AND BEHOLD THREE MEN — **one to announce to Sarah the birth of a son, one to overthrow Sodom, and one to cure Abraham**, ... Raphael who healed Abraham went thence to rescue Lot.

Question: Why did the angel who destroyed Sodom have to visit Avraham?